# EC2 connection using SSH with pem file returns Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, devops

I'm using aws ec2 machine something like 3 weeks and until now everything was working great.

I installed a mongodb server on my machine that required a chown chnages(I think that there was a wrinkle).
I rebooted the machine and from now I get "Permission denied (publickey)." when I'm trying to connect the machine(using ssh -i THE_SAME_PEM_FILE ubuntu@...)
there is another way to connect the machine and to set the configuration as before? or some way to handle that issue?

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Did you chown the .ssh directory or anything in it in the ubuntu user's home directory? No other way into an EC2 instance running linux unless you configured other user's I'm afraid. You may have to create a new instance.

Comment: after reboot ip changed did you tried with new one? and yes chown can break thing

Comment: [Recover Access to EC2 Instances After Losing SSH Key Pair](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-access-lost-key-pair/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution for this, if you are using ssm you can follow the instructions in johns link (comment in your question).
Another option is to detach the volume and add it to another instance you can already ssh to as a data volume. You can add your key to  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file and make sure the permissions are set properly, then reattach the volume to your original instance as the root volume. You will need to stop your instance to detach the volume.
If you don't want to stop the instance, you can take a snapshot of the root volume and then launch another instance using that.